# React Native with Firebase - ERROR Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm working on a React Native project and trying to implement Firebase for push notifications using Firebase Messaging. However, I'm encountering an error that says, "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()".

I've followed the official documentation, and my code seems to be in order. Here's what I've done:

1. I've created a Firebase project in the Firebase Console and obtained the necessary configuration values.
2. I've installed the required packages using npm, including `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/messaging`.
3. I've initialized Firebase with my configuration in my main entry file (app.tsx).
4. I've requested user permission for push notifications and subscribed to incoming messages.

Despite following these steps, I'm still encountering the initialization error. I'm not seeking a specific solution here; instead, I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot this issue further.

If you need to see the code, please let me know, and I'll provide it. Thanks in advance for your help!

├── @babel/core@7.23.2
├── @babel/preset-env@7.23.2
├── @babel/runtime@7.23.2
├── @react-native-firebase/app@18.6.1
├── @react-native-firebase/messaging@18.6.1
├── @react-native/eslint-config@0.72.2
├── @react-native/metro-config@0.72.11
├── @react-navigation/stack@6.3.20
├── @tsconfig/react-native@3.0.2
├── @types/react-test-renderer@18.0.5
├── @types/react@18.2.34
├── babel-jest@29.7.0
├── eslint@8.53.0
├── jest@29.7.0
├── jsi@0.2.5
├── metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.76.8
├── prettier@2.8.8
├── react-native-fast-image@8.6.3
├── react-native-gesture-handler@2.13.4
├── react-native-safe-area-context@4.7.4
├── react-native-screens@3.27.0
├── react-native@0.72.6
├── react-test-renderer@18.2.0
├── react@18.2.0
└── typescript@4.8.4

I try to modify build.gradle and also where was put the init of firebase, but anything changed